# How to switch to Telerik Radwindow using webdriver (java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

We are testing an application build using Telerik.

A demo of Telerik is available here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/radwindowobject/defaultcs.aspx

Our application is build in a similar way.

In this demo you can see a window with Bing in it. I want to switch to it using WebDriver (Java) to perform actions on objects within it.

I have tried to switchto iframe but WebDriver comes back saying it is not an iframe.
Also tried to get window handles and switchto window but with no luck, it is not treated as a new window. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me. I was able to enter text in the bing search field.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/radwindowobject/defaultcs.aspx");
driver.switchTo().frame("RadWindow1");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hello this is my text");
```

Let me know if this helps you.